# How to iterate through the list view and get sum of all edit Text value and show in text view and value in a text view

Tags: android, list, listview

This is my adapter class.In my list i am  having seekbar and edit text .Value of seekbar will show in edit text .I have been trying to get values from all edit text and sum up them and display it n a textview . I wanna do it on edit Text change listener. so the sum value will change simultaneously in a text view.Please help me with this out. Thank u

```
   public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    int value=0;

   ArrayList<RowItem>exp_name=new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    Context context;
    String TAG="myApp";
    StudyExpense study;



    LayoutInflater inflater=null;


    public CustomListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<RowItem>exp_name)
    {

       this.context=context;
       this.exp_name= exp_name;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return exp_name.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view;
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.seek_items,null);
        SeekBar seekBar=(SeekBar)view.findViewById(R.id.seekbarList);
        TextView txtname=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.seekName);


        final EditText txtprice=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.seekprice);
      txtprice.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
          @Override
          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


          }

          @Override
          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


          }
      });


        if(exp_name.get(position).getSeekValue()==0)
        {
            seekBar.setProgress(0);
            txtprice.setText("" + exp_name.get(position).getSeekValue());


        }
        else{
            seekBar.setProgress(exp_name.get(position).getSeekValue());
            txtprice.setText("" + exp_name.get(position).getSeekValue());


        }

        txtname.setText("" + exp_name.get(position).getTitle());

        seekBar.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
        seekBar.setId(position);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {


                txtprice.setText("" + progress);

                exp_name.get(position).setSeekValue(progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
               // int id;
               // id = seekBar.getId();
               // String title = exp_name.get(id).getTitle();

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
        return view;




    }





}
```

Main Activity class(Study Expense)

```
public class StudyExpense extends AppCompatActivity implements  {
    ListView listView;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TextView total;
    ArrayList exp_name = new ArrayList();
    TextView sum;
    Button bt;
    CustomListAdapter adapter;

    String TAG = "myApp";

    public static final String[] titlelist = {"Study Expense", "Travelling Expense", "Household Expense", "Sports Expense", "Entertainment",
            "Food Expense", "Misc Expense"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_study_expense);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, exp_name);
        total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_total);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listexp);
        sum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seekprice);
        bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        listView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(StudyExpense.this, exp_name));
        for (int i = 0; i < titlelist.length; i++) {
            RowItem item = new RowItem();

            item.setTitle(titlelist[i]);

            exp_name.add(item);


        }
```

Comment: you need to take more variables in POJO class in order to achieve your requirement i.e for txtprice

Answer (score 0):

Create a int [] array of your list size in `StudyExpense`

```
public class StudyExpense extends AppCompatActivity implements  {
    ListView listView;
    public static ArrayList<Integer> valueslist;
    ...

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_study_expense);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ....
        for (int i = 0; i < titlelist.length; i++) {
          RowItem item = new RowItem();
          item.setTitle(titlelist[i]);
          exp_name.add(item);
          }
         listView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(StudyExpense.this, exp_name));
         valueslist =  new Arraylist<Integer>(exp_name.size());
        ...}
```

Now make some modification in `CustomListAdapter` class in `getView()` method.

```
   @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view;
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.seek_items,null);
        SeekBar seekBar=(SeekBar)view.findViewById(R.id.seekbarList);
        TextView txtname=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.seekName);


        final EditText txtprice=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.seekprice);
        txtprice.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
          @Override
          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            StudyExpense.valueslist.set(position, Integer.parseInt(s.toString()););
          }

          @Override
          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


          }

  });
```

Now Clicking on any button on execute below code to find out hr sum.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i=0; i<StudyExpense.valueslist.size(); i++){
  sum += StudyExpense.valueslist.get(i);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to perform addition on any click event.. I want to perform when   the values in edit text changes..By default i have assigned 0 value to all edit text. So when user  uses the seekbar  the seekbar value is shown in editext.